# Automatically Convert PNG to JPG with Python

Tags: python, image, mime, jpeg

I've written a Python program to retrieve an image from a URL using

```
msgImage = MIMEImage( urllib2.urlopen(chartURL).read() )
msgRoot.attach(msgImage)
```

The image that I get from the URL is in PNG format, but I would like to embed a JPG version of it.  Is there a simple way to automatically convert the PNG msgImage into JPG for smaller attachments?

Thanks for reading.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PIL: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/
It is easy and it has a lot of documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will look into PIL.  Is there any easier way to do this with built in Python libraries?  Something like msgImage = MIMEImage(...,'jpeg') that tells the MIME package to attach an image (regardless of its initial format)?